# fixed position z-index not working

Tags: css-position, z-index, tumblr

I'm trying to get an image to go over my posts, so the text and images go behind the image. The z-index isn't working when i try to get it to stack over everything. I'm not an expert at coding and I'm honestly just using tumblr for this, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. or one that I can understand, given the fact that I'm still a beginner. Any help would be super appreciated, here's the code:

```
#char {
    position:fixed; 
    opacity: 1.0; 
    width: 1366px; 
    height: 768px; 
    TOP:0px; 
    LEFT:0px; 
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: you should post HTML as well

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code snippet, it contains just a `div`. The `div` overlaps the body. if you provide your source code, I can clarify though. you could also try increasing the z-index to 99 or 999. I think there is many z index'd div's in your code.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #char {
        position:fixed; 
        opacity: 1.0; 
        width: 1366px; 
        height: 768px; 
        TOP:0px; 
        LEFT:0px; 
        z-index: 4;
        background-color: red;
    }
    body{
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
    </style>
    <body>
    <div id="char">
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding the image as a background image to an element and then putting your text in another element inside of that one. With a few lines of alignment code you can get your text where you want it.

```html
<style>
.divStyle {
  background-image: url('http://38.media.tumblr.com/a10b40131efc719d0bff421226b9c52b/tumblr_inline_mq5b19gEvv1qz4rgp.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 90vh; // put this to a 100 to cover the full height of the containing element (less here to avoid scroll bar)
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; //change center to 'flex-start' to move text to top or 'flex-end' to move it to the bottom
}

.myText {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center; //can also be 'left' or 'right'
}
</style>

<div class="divStyle">
  <div class="myText">Here is my text</div>
</div>
```